# Python, decorator that wraps function with "with" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.7+, is there a way to create a decorator that takes something like that:

```py
@some_dec_fun
def fun():
    ...
```

And transforms and executes something like

```py
def fun():
    with some_dec_fun():
        ...
```

Comment: do you have an actual example/use case?

Comment: Checkout [contextlib.ContextDecorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator)

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a decorator to 'get inside' another function. But you can use a decorator to execute the 'whole' decorated function within a particular context.  For example the following will execute the function `some_function` within the context manager `some_context_manager`:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrap():
      with some_context_manager():
          func()
    return wrap()

@my_decorator
def some_function:
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

To add on @match answer, if you need to pass the using resource as argument to your decorator, you can use the following code:

```py
def using_dec(using_expr):
    def wrapper(func):
        def aux(*args, **kwargs):
            with using_expr():
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return aux
    return wrapper
```

and use it like this:

```py
@using_dec(lambda : open("resource", 'w'))
def hello(x):
    print("hello " + str(x))
```